# Limit http request from same IP address (Ubuntu + nginx)

Tags: linux, nginx, ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04

is there any default limitation on Nginx or ubuntu for HTTP requests with the same IP address? because sometimes when our client uses several devices with the same IP address, and do an HTTP request, some devices appear to be really slow to respond and other devices get a 403 error. But if the IP address were different, it run just fine.

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 + Nginx for my web apps. I haven't done any configuration just default setting and I'm fairly new to operating a web server so I really don't know much. Any help is appreciated, thank you.